# Split the value from property using ANT

Tags: ant, foreach

I have the following code:

```
<dirset id="aa" dir="FOLDER" includes="example*" excludes=".*">
</dirset>
<pathconvert pathsep="," property="bb" refid="aa">
<mapper type="flatten"/> 
</pathconvert>  
<echo message="LIST:${bb}"/>
```

and the output is for example 'examle.aa,example.bb'

And I would like to call another target for each example.*.. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

A macrodef would work for this, you could invoke it with custom attributes or elements based on you current property:

[macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try [antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) for the loop functionality.  Here's an example

```
<project>

    <target name="test">
        <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpath="./lib/ant-contrib-1.0.jar" />

        <for param="file">
            <dirset dir="." />

            <sequential>
                <task dir="@{file}" />
            </sequential>
        </for>
    </target>


    <macrodef name="task">
        <attribute name="dir" />

        <sequential>
            <echo>@{dir}</echo>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

</project>
```